# Which Asian player has the most goals in Top 5 European leagues?

Tags: football, trivia, top-five

Which Asian player has the most goals in Top 5 European leagues?

Answer (score 1):

[Cha Bum-kun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha_Bum-kun) scored 98 goals in the Bundesliga, but [Son Heung-min](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_Heung-min) is likely to surpass this in the near future, having so far scored 88 goals (41 in the Bundesliga, 47 in the Premier League).